# algorithm to compute if a dollar value is possible with 100 coins

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Tomorrow my son has to bring in 100 of something to share for his 100th day of class. I wanted to use pennies but he said that too many people are doing this. Is there a dynamic programming algo that will will allow me to produce all dollar values possible with 100 coins including dollar coins?

acceptable values are 1, 5, 10, 25, 100. Max value is 10000.

Just trying to make my son happy and provide some knowledge to the class at the same time. Any help is appreciated, I don't want to be that dad that just sends 100 pennies. This isn't about providing a solution with the least number of coins, more about providing a solution with an exact number of coins.

Comment: Is it really a good idea to send your child to school with $100 in coins?

Comment: He has a great teacher and she would absolutely send all of the money back. More importantly this isn't about money, it's about making my son happy and teaching him the value of computing. And I would probably pick a number closer to 10 or 25.

Comment: @Vikram, not faking, I posted my solution. At my school nobody would be interested in this algorithm, it's too simple. If I had remembered to do it this weekend I wouldn't be here. Sorry if you don't believe me but if you read the thread you would see that nobody provided me this solution. I spent more time on SO and found some code that I could modify to fit my needs.

Comment: @Chris.Stover sorry then but please avoid this sort of structuring of problem it corresponds to overacting but as you have found solution then i believe you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the final code that I ended up using. It is a modified version of code found on an SO question:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int total = 100;

    while (total < 2501){
        int combos = 0;

        for (int q = 0; q <= total / 25; q++)
        {
            int total_less_q = total - q * 25;
            for (int d = 0; d <= total_less_q / 10; d++)
            {
                int total_less_q_d = total_less_q - d * 10;
                for (int n = 0; n <= total_less_q_d / 5; n++)
                {
                    int p = total_less_q_d - n * 5;
                    if((q+d+n+p) == 100){
                        if(q < 9 && d < 14 && n < 5 && p < 100) {
                            printf("total: %d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",
                                   total, q, d, n, p);
                        }
                    }
                    combos++;
                }
            }
        }
        total++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if syntax is messed up, I have other things to worry about tonight. The number of quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies that I had in the house are hard coded so if this code will ever be reused change those values.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done 'by the hand'. Suppose that you have set of coins which can produce all values up to value V. They maybe can produce even some larger values but not value V+1. If you add coin to that set that has value n <= V+1, than new set can produce all values up to V+n. With that it is enough to ask what is largest consecutive value that my set can produce, and for next coin to take choose largest coin that is <= V+1.

E.g. to produce 1, we need coin with value 1. If we don't have it, we are stuck :-)

```
{1} -> V=1 -> next coin is 1
{2*1} -> V=2 -> next coin is 1
{3*1} -> V=3 -> next coin is 1
{4*1} -> V=4 -> next coin is 5
{4*1, 5} -> V=9 -> next coin is 10
{4*1, 5, 10} -> V=19 -> next coin is 10
{4*1, 5, 2*10} -> V=29 -> next coin is 25
{4*1, 5, 2*10, 25} -> V=54 -> next coin is 50
...
```